# Extra UIButton appearing at bottom of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I'm implementing a "delete" button on a UITableViewFeed. The delete button should only appear when the post is by the current user. My logic seems to be working fine for all of the feed, except for the bottom, where the "delete" button appears regardless. I've tried changing the color/properties of the button on the last cell, but nothing happens and it remains there, which suggests there's some sort of other error that places it at the bottom of the UITableView.

Here's an overview of my logic:

```
if (([[user objectId] isEqualToString:[currentUser objectId]]) && [user objectId]) 
{   
     cell.trashcanButton = [[TrashcanButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70, HEIGHT_OF_IMAGE_WRAP - 40, 25, 25)];
     [cell.trashcanButton addTarget:self action:@selector(deletePost:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
     [cell.viewForBaselineLayout addSubview:cell.trashcanButton];
} 
else 
{
     NSLog(@"the button should not appear"); //this is registered for the last cell (bottom of feed)
     cell.trashcanButton.hidden = YES;
}
```

Why is the button appearing at the bottom of the feed, even when the NSLog statement is registered for the last cell?

Comment: are you using storyboard for creating this tableviewcell or its in code? can you show full cellForRow method

Comment: The problem is that you are reusing the subviews but you still are adding a subView. Check the line 

    [cell.viewForBaselineLayout addSubview:cell.trashcanButton];

You can add an if condition to verify that you haven't add cell.trashcanButton you might be adding it twice remember that tableView uses dequeWithReusableIdentifier which might be reusing a view and readding the subview